# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression - Access16

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I am getting the following error message when attempting to save or run a SQL query in MS Access 2016:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'M.ScheduleKey FROM Actual_Data A'

The Query is:

```
UPDATE Actual_Data
SET A.ScheduleKey = M.ScheduleKey
FROM Actual_Data A, Match M
WHERE A.ActualKey = M.ActualKey
```

Both the ScheduleKey & ActualKey fields are text fields.

Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead:

```sql
UPDATE Actual_Data A
INNER JOIN Match M
ON A.ActualKey = M.ActualKey
SET A.ScheduleKey = M.ScheduleKey
```